# How do you give a <hr> a gradient color?

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal rule on my html page with the following styling applied:

```
#seperate {
    clear: both;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Is it possible to make the horizontal rule's colour a gradient similar to:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow)
```

I have attempted doing this..

```
#seperate {
clear: both;
border: 3px solid linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow);
}
```

..but that failed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, just provide some height to the `hr`

```css
hr {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<hr/>
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is your gradient

```css
body{
  padding:20px;
}

.hr1 {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

```html
<hr class="hr1" />
```

Comment: The Best Answer it should marked :) Thank Alot

Answer (score 2):

Please add the below CSS

```
#seperate {
  height: 3px;
  background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */ 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow); /*For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */ 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */ 
 background: linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow); /* Standard syntax */ }
}
```

Please check the Fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/pqrudt6j/