# border-color with linear-gradient

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

```
<hr class="instagram">
```

I am trying to use Linear Gradient with `<hr>` tag for coloring the line. Is it a valid action? If not how can I achieve that?

```
.instagram {
  color: linear-gradient(to right, hsl(37, 97%, 70%), hsl(329, 70%, 58%)); /* Not Working */
  border-width: medium;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-block-start: 0px;
  margin-block-end: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of border, use `height` and `background-image` for the linear gradient.

```css
.instagram {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, hsl(37, 97%, 70%), hsl(329, 70%, 58%));
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<hr class="instagram">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `background` instead of `color` and a `height` :

```
 background: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
 height: 5px;
```

As recommanded on this post [How do you give a <hr> a gradient color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50576507/how-do-you-give-a-hr-a-gradient-color)

Answer (score 0):

I see you don't have any height on your hr — and perhaps change color to background. I also added different browser support. Try this:

```
.instagram {
  height: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
background: hsl(37, 97%, 70%); /* not all browsers support gradients */ 
  background: linear-gradient(to right, hsl(37, 97%, 70%), hsl(329, 70%, 58%)) /* standard syntax */ 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, hsl(37, 97%, 70%), hsl(329, 70%, 58%)); /*For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(to right, hsl(37, 97%, 70%), hsl(329, 70%, 58%)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */ 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, hsl(37, 97%, 70%), hsl(329, 70%, 58%)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do it:

```css
.instagram {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, hsl(37, 97%, 70%), hsl(329, 70%, 58%)) border-box;
  border: medium solid transparent;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<hr class="instagram">
```